# how can i prettier template literal in javascript with intellij

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, code-formatting

i use template literal in javaScript

```
let innerHTML = `<div><span>like this</span></div>`;
```

is it possible to automatically indent or prettier like jsx in intellij?

when i press [ ctrl + alt + l ] change nothing

i want to make this format automatically

```
let innerHTML = `<div>
                     <span>
                         like this
                     </span>
                 </div>`;
```

is it possible?

Comment: Is such an HTML  fragment formatted correctly if pasted in HTML file? In JSX file is it highlighted as HTML (are tags recognized?)? Does it help if you add  //language=HTML comment before the declaration?

Comment: "//language=HTML" is very suitable solution , thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply add a comment before your template string and Prettier will pick it up:

```js
function vanillaComponent() {
  return /* HTML */ `
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  `
}
```

At the moment the comment has to be uppercase or it doesn't work. Tested using VSCode.

Comment: tested also in Webstorm this works  this did not work in WS for me html`

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Prettier, you should use a template literal tag to mark it as HTML, otherwise it doesn't know that that string contains HTML.

Prettier calls this [embedded language](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#embedded-language-formatting), you can see below that this also enables various syntax highlighters.

This line:

```js
let innerHTML = html`
  <div><span> This is a very long line that should be wrapped 123456789 123456789 123456789 </span></div>
`;
```

Is wrapped as

```
let innerHTML = html`
  <div>
    <span>
      This is a very long line that should be wrapped 123456789 123456789
      123456789
    </span>
  </div>
`;
```

You can get this `html` function and others from [`code-tag`](https://github.com/fregante/code-tag):

```bash
npm install code-tag
```

```js
import { html } from 'code-tag';

html`<div>this is page "${document.title}"`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio Code you can use this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobermory.es6-string-html

(I'm sure there is equivalent extension for others IDE)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tagged templates;

```
const innerHtml = html`
    <img src=${Icon} id="content-logo" />
   `;
```

If you faced this kind of error: `ReferenceError: html is not defined`. You can define `html` function by your own;

```
const html = (strings, ...values) =>
  String.raw({ raw: strings }, ...values);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#raw_strings